# Excel macro that hides a given number of rows

Tags: vba, excel

I was searching for answers regarding this issue, but no luck. 
I want an excel macro to hides rows based on a cell value.
My table is between row 18 and row 418 could you please take a look at my VBA code:

```
Sub HideRows()

Dim np As Integer

np = Range("W1").Value
'hidding all the table rows first                
ActiveSheet.Rows("18:418").EntireRow.Hidden = True
'showing only from row 18 to the number given by cell "W1"
ActiveSheet.Rows("18:np").EntireRow.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

It is giving me a type mismatch an error, is there any way to make this work? Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
ActiveSheet.Rows("18:np").EntireRow.Hidden = False
```

to

```
ActiveSheet.Rows("18:" & np).EntireRow.Hidden = False
```

Comment: Nice, I was gone for 2 weeks and you climbed to 12K :)

Comment: @ShaiRado - there's more rep available when you aren't answering all the questions :D

Comment: @YowE3K - Another veteran returned, shall I call everyone to abandon ship? :))

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go

```
Sub HideRows()

Dim np As Long

    np = Range("W1").Row
    'hidding all the table rows first                
    ActiveSheet.Range("18:418").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    'showing only from row 18 to the number given by cell "W1"
    ActiveSheet.Range("18:np").EntireRow.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

Also, it's better to `Dim` most numbers as `Long` rather than `Integer`. `Long` has a longer character size (i.e. you can use bigger numbers where as Integer's max is ±32767) This is worth noting if you're looping through a large data set. Also VBA treats them exactly the same on a 32-Bit environment - When it compiles it converts `Integer's to`Long`.
[Int & Long Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3042759)